# Does anybody know reconnoiter?

Tags: monitoring, debian-lenny

How do I install [reconnoiter](https://labs.omniti.com/labs/reconnoiter) onto Debian?

Comment: Did the "step-by-step guide to installing on Debian" from the linked page not work?  If it did not work, what problems did you have?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to build it from source. There are instructions [here](http://www.ducea.com/2010/07/13/howto-install-reconnoiter-on-debian-lenny/) on how to do this.

Comment: Okay, how do i get the reconnoiter-graph in apache web server by specifying the datapoint like display math and source math?

Comment: as per instructions, wherein I did not find any demo on datapoints or dataset like display math and source math?

Comment: @Nagaraj: if you now have Reconnoiter installed and want help configuring it then you should ask for that help in a different question.

Comment: @lain:okay, Thank you. I have installed reconnoiter apache web server in that wherein I can view option like "Username" and "Logout". Now If anybody wants to access reconnoiter apache web server requires user id and password to access the server. Is there any coding do we need to set for username and password.